# Statics Beam Problem

Tags: statics

Can I get some guidance on this beam problem I'm trying to solve. I basically know only one force value as you can see in my FBD.

It's clearly statically indeterminate, but is there a way to find the two reaction forces?

[image: Free Body Diagram]

Comment: Split it into 3 load cases, find the deflection at the the locations of interest due to each force, adjust the reaction forces so  the deflection at the two rollers sums to 0. Method of superposition is the sesquipedalian description.